# Hive timestamp format

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

I have some data with the following format:

```
28/04/2017 00:00:00|20550|22/05/2017 00:00:00|
```

I am setting `|` as a separator. For the data in the first and third row in this example, I put `timestamp` as a data type in HUE, but I get `null`s as answer.

I have looked around and it seems to me like Hive supports Unix format timestamp (from places like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31065681/6028947) )

But, I get a "Invalid date" message (I'm doing it with HUE so far, I'm still new with this technologies). If I try to make this data String, I can see values, but when I try to use `to_date()` the problem persists.

Is there anything I'm ignoring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only supported timestamp format is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` with optional fraction of seconds.
Anything else should be read as string and converted later.

#### Demo

```
with t as (select '28/04/2017 00:00:00' as mydate)
select  from_unixtime(to_unix_timestamp (mydate,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss'))
from    t
```

> 2017-04-28 00:00:00

Comment: Oooh so it is yyyy*-*MM*-*dd right? Like, are the "-" symbol a strict restriction? If so, is there any function to format the date, other than toDate, or something more programaticaly like a spark job required? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @monkeyintern - sorry for the delay, check the updated answer